# помогите с передачей из сервлета в javascript параметров запроса

Tags: javascript, java, json, post, servlet

пару дней уже не могу понять, есть на странице форма с отправкой методом post, я хочу получить из нее данные и передать на другую страницу и получить их там, получить данные в сервлете получается, как их передать на другую html страницу чтобы можно было вывести через javascript? через get можно просто через location.search найти нужные параметры и делать что то с ними, через post не получается, подскажите как это можно провернуть

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум - это присвоение к названию страницы ключевых слов и с их значением. На мой взгляд, именно так и нужно делать.  Я про запросы такого типа: `post.html?name=Alex&email=@gmail.com&message=text-this-message`

Comment: @Egor а как потом в скрипте получить эти значения?

Comment: Внедрите данные на страницу. Например выводом скрипта <script>,  xml, скрытых элементов, скрытых полей ввода. Есть варианты.

Comment: либо страница должна запросить данные сама, либо websocket